# I am creating a text based adventure game for a class and having trouble getting my inventory system to work

Tags: python

For the previous week's assignment in my class we had to create a simple, working game that allowed moving rooms.  I have adjusted that code into my game code and it seems to work fine, even with the addition of 'Item' into my dictionary.  Once I try to add to the inventory and reference the inventory list to the dictionary keys I get an 'unhashable' error.  I looked this up but the only way to clear the error is to use a tuple, but a tuple is immutable so I wouldn't be able to add to the inventory, at least as I understand it.  Any guidance or suggestions is much appreciated!

```
def player_instructions():
    # main menu and game commands
    print('Move Commands: go North, go South, go West, go East')
    print("Add to inventory: get 'item name'.")
    print('-' * 50)


print('A Paladin Adventure Game.')  # game opening greeting
print('Collect 7 items to win the game,')
print('or be destroyed by the Vampire Lord.')
print('-' * 50)

# dictionary for rooms and movement between
castle_rooms = {'Entry Hall': {'East': 'Great Hall', 'South': 'Solar', 'Item': ''},
                'Great Hall': {'West': 'Entry Hall', 'South': 'Boudoir',
                               'North': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Cabinet', 'Item': 'Silver Mail'},
                'Solar': {'North': 'Entry Hall', 'East': 'Boudoir', 'Item': 'Stake'},
                'Boudoir': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'West': 'Solar', 'Item': 'Holy Water'},
                'Kitchen': {'East': 'Larder', 'South': 'Great Hall', 'Item': 'Mallet'},
                'Larder': {'West': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'Potion of Cleansing'},
                'Cabinet': {'West': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Garderobe', 'South': 'Bedchamber',
                            'Item': 'Blessed Sword'},
                'Garderobe': {'South': 'Cabinet', 'Item': 'Torch'}
                }

current_room = 'Entry Hall'  # define starting room
inventory = []  # define string for inventory


def player_commands(command, direction):  # function for moving rooms
    global current_room  # declare current room as global
    global inventory  # declare inventory as global
    if command == 'go':
        if direction in castle_rooms[current_room]:  # establishing valid direction
            current_room = castle_rooms[current_room][direction]
        elif direction not in castle_rooms[current_room]:  # error message for invalid direction
            print("You can't go that way")
            current_room = current_room

    elif command == 'get':
        if direction in current_room:
            inventory.append(direction)
        current_room = current_room
    else:
        print('Invalid command')  # error message for invalid command
        current_room = current_room
    return current_room, inventory


while current_room != 'Bedchamber':  # while loop for gameplay
    player_instructions()
    print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_room))

    if castle_rooms[current_room]['Item'] not in inventory:
        print('You see {} in the room.'.format(castle_rooms[current_room]['Item']))
    else:
        pass
    user_input = input('What will you do next?').split()
    command = user_input[0]
    direction = user_input[1] if len(user_input) > 1 else ''
    current_room = player_commands(command, direction)
```

This is the entire code so far, everything worked until I tried adding a separate player inventory.  I haven't added the game end code yet so I realize I have an infinite loop but I was trying to make the inventory work before I added the ending since the inventory has to include all items to win.

Comment: With you handling of the `"get"` command, you want to test if an item is in the inventory and append it if not. You then likely want to set the room item to None.

Comment: Should I make a second list for that? or can I remove it from the dictionary?  I think I need another statement for 'Item' not being in the dictionary, I set my Entry Hall 'Item' as '' to stop another error, maybe a if/elif statement.  I'm still not sure that will fix the unhashable error though.

    if castle_rooms[current_room]['Item'] not in inventory:
        print('You see {} in the room.'.format(castle_rooms[current_room]['Item']))
    elif 'Item' not in castle_rooms[current_room]:
        pass
maybe something like this, of course that only addresses showing that it is in the room

Comment: Sorry, new to this, I guess I don't know how to show the code in a comment.

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Instead, [edit] your question to clarify it or provide additional examples or explanations. Your question shoud be self-contained, anyway; not all visitors will want to, or even be able to, read all comments.

Answer (score 2):

When you "get" an item, you want to append it to your inventory and remove it from the room.

Try something like:

```py
    elif command == 'get':
        current_item = castle_rooms[current_room_id]['Item']
        if current_item not in inventory:
            inventory.append(current_item)
            castle_rooms[current_room_id]['Item'] = None
            return current_room_id
```

If you are getting an error around line 56 of so that is (based on your original code) likely:

```py
    if castle_rooms[current_room]['Item'] not in inventory:
        print('You see {} in the room.'.format(castle_rooms[current_room]['Item']))
    else:
        pass
```

If a room does not have an item, then this will throw a key error. Try replacing that code with:

```py
    current_room_item = castle_rooms[current_room].get('Item')
    if current_room_item not in inventory:
        print('You see {} in the room.'.format(current_room_item ))
```

Here is a more complete example:

```py
import time

def player_instructions():
    # main menu and game commands
    print('Move Commands:\n\tgo North, go South, go West, go East')
    print("Inventory Commands:\n\tshow, take")

def player_commands(command, direction):  # function for moving rooms
    global current_room_id  # declare current room as global
    global inventory  # declare inventory as global

    if command == 'show':
        if not inventory:
            print("Your backpack is empty.")
            return current_room_id
        
        print("You have the following items:")
        for item in inventory:
            print(f"    - {item}")
        return current_room_id

    if command == 'take':
        current_item = castle_rooms[current_room_id]['Item']

        if not current_item:
            print(f"There is nothing here to take")
            return current_room_id

        if current_item in inventory:
            print(f"You already have the {current_item}")
            return current_room_id

        print(f"You greedily take the {current_item}")
        inventory.append(current_item)
        castle_rooms[current_room_id]['Item'] = None
        return current_room_id

    if command == 'go':
        if direction not in castle_rooms[current_room_id]:
            print("You can't go that way")
            return current_room_id

        print(f"You head {direction} out of the {current_room_id}.")
        return castle_rooms[current_room_id][direction]

    print('Invalid command')  # error message for invalid command
    return current_room_id

## -----------------------
# dictionary for rooms and movement between
## -----------------------
castle_rooms = {
    'Entry Hall': {'East': 'Great Hall', 'South': 'Solar', 'Item': None},
    'Great Hall': {'West': 'Entry Hall', 'South': 'Boudoir', 'North': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Cabinet', 'Item': 'Silver Mail'},
    'Solar': {'North': 'Entry Hall', 'East': 'Boudoir', 'Item': 'Stake'},
    'Boudoir': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'West': 'Solar', 'Item': 'Holy Water'},
    'Kitchen': {'East': 'Larder', 'South': 'Great Hall', 'Item': 'Mallet'},
    'Larder': {'West': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'Potion of Cleansing'},
    'Cabinet': {'West': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Garderobe', 'South': 'Bedchamber', 'Item': 'Blessed Sword'},
    'Garderobe': {'South': 'Cabinet', 'Item': 'Torch'}
}
## -----------------------

current_room_id = 'Entry Hall'  # define starting room
inventory = []  # define string for inventory

print('-' * 50)
print('A Paladin Adventure Game.')  # game opening greeting
print('Collect 7 items to win the game,')
print('or be destroyed by the Vampire Lord.')

while current_room_id != 'Bedchamber':  # while loop for gameplay
    current_room = castle_rooms[current_room_id]
    current_room_item = current_room['Item']
    current_room_exits = [key for key in current_room if key != "Item"]

    print('-' * 50)
    print(f'You are in the {current_room_id}.')
    print(f'The following exits are visible: {current_room_exits}')
    if current_room_item:
        print(f'You see the {current_room_item} in the room.')
    player_instructions()

    command = input('What will you do next? ')
    direction = None
    if " " in command:
        command, direction = command.split()

    current_room_id = player_commands(command, direction)
    time.sleep(2)

print("Congrats, you reached the Bedchamber!")
```

Comment: That certainly works to prevent the error in the code, I tried something similar by making 'Item' : '' in the dictionary.  The problem is I need to be able to print the item in the room if it exists and if I don't have an 'Item' key it gives me an error, I'm not sure how to work around the 'Item' problem yet.

Comment: @Daelinia `if castle_rooms[current_room_id].get('Item'): print(castle_rooms[current_room_id]['Item'])`

Comment: will that help me get rid of this error?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DellUser\PycharmProjects\IT140project\PaladinAdventure.py", line 56, in <module>
    if castle_rooms[current_room]['Item'] == 'None':  # inform player of 'Item' in current room
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: See my latest update to the answer that hopefully addresses this error for you.

Comment: This won't let me edit my original post with the code I've written, if I put it in an answer will it close the question?  I think I don't understand dictionaries well enough, I'm having a problem in one of the labs for this week as well.

Comment: It is the code around line 56 that is throwing the error, I don't even get to trying the get 'Item' command because as soon as I move rooms it throws the error and exits the program.  I'll have to try your fix for that and see what it does then.

Comment: unfortunately it still throws the same error, I guess tomorrow I'll use the tutoring tool SNHU offers and see if I can address it there, I only have til Sunday to get it done but I work the rest of this week too, time to get ready for work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let me see if I can post a complete working example for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is import time necessary?  We haven't gone into that yet, I'm a total beginner LoL 7th week of my intro class, so I have no idea what that does, although I have seen it a few times through my research.  I'll make adjustments to the inventory process and see if that fixes my problem but I think I'll have to go through the tutoring anyway since they know exactly what is expected for the project.  Thank you so much for all your help, I feel like I at least understand the dictionary part a little better.

Comment: `import time` just allows us to put a little pause in between actions. you can take it out and then also take out `time.sleep(2)`

Answer (score 0):

So I worked with a friend that knows python and he taught me some really neat new things, adding color to the code and he also helped me fix my inventory problems  I think the inline comments explain most of what is going on with it, I'm so excited to have it working well.

```
    RED = '\033[91m'
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    YELLOW = '\033[93m'
    BLUE = '\033[94m'
    DARK_PURPLE = '\033[38;5;127m'
    CYAN = '\033[96m'
    VIOLET = '\033[95m'
    RESET = '\033[0m'

def player_instructions():
    # main menu and game commands
    print(f"{TextColor.GREEN}Move Commands{TextColor.RESET}: go North, go South, go West, go East")
    print(f"{TextColor.YELLOW}Add to inventory{TextColor.RESET}: get item name")
    print(f"{TextColor.BLUE}View inventory{TextColor.RESET}: inventory")
    print('-' * 50)


print('A Paladin Adventure Game.')  # game opening greeting
print(f"Collect {TextColor.RED}7{TextColor.RESET} items to win the game,")
print('or be destroyed by the Vampire Lord.')
print('-' * 50)

# dictionary for rooms and movement, and items and inventory
castle_rooms = {
    'Entry Hall': {
        'East': 'Great Hall',
        'South': 'Solar',
        'Item': 'None'
    },
    'Great Hall': {
        'West': 'Entry Hall',
        'South': 'Boudoir',
        'North': 'Kitchen',
        'East': 'Cabinet',
        'Item': 'Silver Mail'
    },
    'Solar': {
        'North': 'Entry Hall',
        'East': 'Boudoir',
        'Item': 'Stake'
    },
    'Boudoir': {
        'North': 'Great Hall',
        'West': 'Solar',
        'Item': 'Holy Water'
    },
    'Kitchen': {
        'East': 'Larder',
        'South': 'Great Hall',
        'Item': 'Mallet'
    },
    'Larder': {
        'West': 'Kitchen',
        'Item': 'Torch'
    },
    'Cabinet': {
        'West': 'Great Hall',
        'North': 'Garderobe',
        'South': 'Bedchamber',
        'Item': 'Blessed Sword'
    },
    'Garderobe': {
        'South': 'Cabinet',
        'Item': 'Potion of Cleansing'
    }
}


current_room = 'Entry Hall'  # define starting room
inventory = []  # define string for inventory


def display_inventory(current_inventory):
    if not current_inventory:
        print("Your inventory is empty.")
    else:
        print("Your inventory:")
        for item in inventory:
            print("- {}{}{}".format(TextColor.VIOLET, item, TextColor.RESET))


def player_commands(cmd, dir_value):
    global current_room
    global inventory

    # Set default values
    new_current_room = current_room
    new_inventory = inventory

    if cmd == 'go':
        # Handle movement logic
        if dir_value in castle_rooms[current_room]:
            new_current_room = castle_rooms[current_room][dir_value]
        else:
            print("You can't go that way")

    elif cmd == 'get':
        # handle inventory and working with the dictionary
        cleaned_dir = dir_value.strip("'")
        if cleaned_dir == castle_rooms[current_room]['Item']:
            item_name = castle_rooms[current_room]['Item']
            if item_name != 'None':
                new_inventory.append(item_name)
                castle_rooms[current_room]['Item'] = 'None'
                print("You've added {}{}{} to your inventory.".format(TextColor.VIOLET, item_name, TextColor.RESET))
            else:
                print("There's no item here to get.")
        else:
            print("You can't get that here.")

    else:
        print('Invalid command')

    return new_current_room, new_inventory


while current_room != 'Bedchamber':  # while loop for gameplay
    player_instructions()

    player_room = castle_rooms[current_room]  # make current exits visible
    current_room_exits = [key for key in player_room if key != 'Item']

    print('You are in the {}{}{}.'.format(TextColor.DARK_PURPLE, current_room, TextColor.RESET))
    print('The following exits are visible: {}{}{}'.format(TextColor.CYAN, current_room_exits, TextColor.RESET))
    if castle_rooms[current_room]['Item'] != 'None':  # inform player of item in room
        item_name = castle_rooms[current_room]['Item']
        print('You see {}{}{} in the room.'.format(TextColor.VIOLET, item_name, TextColor.RESET))

    user_input = input('What will you do next? ').split(maxsplit=1)
    command = user_input[0]
    direction = user_input[1] if len(user_input) > 1 else ''
    direction = direction.strip("'")  # Remove single quotes from direction

    if command == 'inventory':   # for inventory display
        display_inventory(inventory)
    else:
        current_room, inventory = player_commands(command, direction)

if current_room == 'Bedchamber':
    # game ending conditions

    if len(inventory) == 7:  # winning ending
        print('Congratulations!')
        print('You have defeated the Vampire Lord and retained your humanity.')
        print('You win!')
        print('-' * 50)
        exit()
    elif len(inventory) == 6:
        if 'Potion of Cleansing' not in inventory:  # alternate win/lose ending
            print('Congratulations!')
            print('You have defeated the Vampire Lord!')
            print('However, you did not find the Potion of Cleansing.')
            print('You are doomed to become the next Lord of the Castle.')
            print('-' * 50)
            exit()
        else:
            print('You did not collect all of the items needed')  # loss
            print('to defeat the Vampire Lord.')
            print('You lose.')
            print('-' * 50)
            exit()
    else:
        print('You did not collect all of the items needed')  # loss
        print('to defeat the Vampire Lord.')
        print('You lose.')
        print('-' * 50)
        exit()
```